# Wifi not working on Acer Aspire 5570z

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I recently installed ubuntu 13.10 on the computer to get some use out of it. I have no clue why the wifi is not working as a day ago it had Windows Vista and was. I have installed the proprietary driver for networking and it had made it no better. I have also installed all update using ethernet. Why is the wifi not working?

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4352] (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0110]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at 44000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: sky2

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device [1468:0422]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 44500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: wl

0a:09.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller [104c:8039]
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0110]
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 20
    Memory at d0204000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Bus: primary=0a, secondary=0b, subordinate=0e, sec-latency=176
    Memory window 0: 40000000-43ffffff (prefetchable)

Comment: pls post the output of lspci -vnn | grep -i net -A 12

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just type the command I posted, and post the output here

Comment: I put the output in the question as it was to long.

Comment: The 4311 (at least as of 12.04) still required you to use b43-fwcutter. Look here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

and here:

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices

Comment: PLease see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ethernet working, it is quite easy. If you do not have any internet connection on your system, just let me know and I will post a different solution, suitable to this case.

Issue the following commands:

```
   sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
   sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot, it should work.

Comment: Just did this and made no change.

Comment: @Brandon make sure the module b43 is loaded, by checking modinfo | grep b43. Empty output, it is not loaded: force its loading with sudo modprobe b43. Some output, it is correctly loaded but does not work: in this case dmesg | grep wlan0, dmesg | grep b43, post the output.

Comment: Alright. I got caught up with school, and the holidays. So I am going to completely wipe the computer and freshly install Ubuntu 13.10. And if it does not work then I will ask what to do.

Comment: @Brandon Ok,, that sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Okay I now have a fresh install with all the updates installed. what should I do next?